# addClass to variable and append jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, addclass, var

I'm having some problems when trying to add a class to a variable and then append this to another div. When I do this, the text appears but without the class I am trying to add to it. I am doing all of this with jQuery.

This is the code:

```
var names = $(this).attr('name');
var description = $(this).attr('description');
var url = $(this).attr('url');

$(names).addClass("nam");


$(div1).append( names + " " + description + " " + url);
});
```

I guess I am doing something wrong but can't see where.

Comment: What are the attributes `'name'`, `'description'` and `'url'` can you give us an example of the html of `this` element

Comment: The attributes are different contents of an .xml

Comment: Can you tell me what the xml node will look like and what the desired appended content of $(div1) should be

Comment: Sure, the xml looks like this:<Blogs>
  <blog name="number1"
        description="1"
        url=" http://www.1.com/"/>
  <blog name="number2"
        description="2"
        url="http://www.2.com/"/>
  <blog name="number3"
        description="3"
        url="http://www.3.com" />"
</Blogs>

Comment: the content is only text which i want to give a class

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a jQuery wrapper for `name` and adding a class to it but then you are appending the previous string reference instead of the jQuery wrapper to which the class was added.

Also you can't add class to a text node so try wrapping it with a span element(if `name` is not a html content like `<span>some name</span>`)

```
var names = $('<span />', {
    text : $(this).attr('name'),
    'class' : 'nam'
})
var description = $(this).attr('description');
var url = $(this).attr('url');


$(div1).append( names).append( " " + description + " " + url);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to do `$(names).addClass("nam");` when you have `'class' : 'nam'`

Comment: Thanks Arun P Johny, but I tried what you suggested but didn't work, now the names are not appearing. I forgot to tell you that the attributes are text from an .xml, maybe thats why it doesn't work. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

First off for this answer I am assuming we're using an xml string of the format you provided in your comment on op. Note - I did correct the syntax of the string to remove the extraneous semi colons.

```
var xmlstring = '<Blogs> <blog name="number1" description="1" url=" 1.com/"/> <blog name="number2" description="2" url="2.com/"/> <blog name="number3" description="3" url="3.com;" />" </Blogs>'
```

Now we can parse this string as expected into a jQuery object and use mostly as expected:
`var $doc = $($.parseXML(xmlstring));`

I'm assuming in your original example that `this` blog refers to one of these sub blogs so I'm going to say for my example:

```
var $this = $doc.find("blog:eq(2)");//the blog name=number3 in your example 
//OR
var $this = $(this);//useful so we dont keep rewrapping
```

Okay so now we have our blog (`$this`) and we can append the contents to `div1` as follows:

```
var names = $("<span>", {text:$this.attr('name'), 'class': 'nam'});
var description = $this.attr('description');
var url = $this.attr('url');

$(div1).append( names, description + " " + url);//as names is a span element
```

I tested this on an empty div and it produced the following outerhtml:
`"<div><span class="nam">number3</span>3 3.com;</div>"`

Hope this helped, I tried to explain steps because I'm not sure where what you're doing was deviating.